# dax/powerbi difference between calculate and calculatetable functions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to powerbi and trying to understand difference between `CALCULATETABLE` and `CALCULATE`. I read these [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculatetable-function-dax),[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax) pages. I am not clear. It says that `Whereas the CALCULATE function requires as its first argument an expression that returns a single value, the CALCULATETABLE function takes a table of values.` Could anyone explain it further?

## update 1

1) it seems that `CALCULATETABLE` works on a table of data while `CALCULATE` works on a single value. is there any difference in terms of output?

2) could anyone guide when it is better to use one of these functions over other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the most fundamental function in DAX. Thy are used when you need to change the context where the expression (first parameter of the function) is evaluated.
The difference between the two functions is related to the input type and the output type.

[CALCULATE](https://dax.guide/sum) function takes as input an expression that evaluates to scalar and returns a scalar value.
[CALCULATETABLE](https://dax.guide/sum) function takes as input an expression that evaluates to table and returns a table.

Therefore, if you need to change the context where a scalar expression is evaluated, use `CALCULATE`. If you need to change the context where a table expression is evaluated, use `CALCULATETABLE`.

#### Expressions

An expression that evaluates to scalar is everything that returns you a scalar. For example, [SUM()](https://dax.guide/sum), [MIN()](https://dax.guide/min), [MAX()](https://dax.guide/max) they all returns you a single value.
An expression that evaluates to table is everything that returns you a table. For example, 'My Table'[My Field] and [VALUES](https://dax.guide/values)('My Table'[My Field]) both returns you a table.

#### Sources

Finally, how can you know input type and output type of dax functions? My favourite source is [dax.guide](https://dax.guide)

Comment: could anyone guide when it is better to use one of these functions over other?

Comment: update the answer. However, this is extremely basic I suggest to check out some (free) beginner video on sqlbi.com to grasp main DAX concepts.

Comment: Calculate is the most important function in DAX.  Here are some links: https://www.daxpatterns.com/time-patterns/ https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/ https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/definitive-guide-to-dax-business-intelligence-with-9780735698352